# how to pass value to html and update the screen, with package flutter_html

Tags: html, flutter

here is my code, I want to pass and update the value `name` , but in the end on the screen there is only $name displaying, instead of what I did input, please help me and show any idea, thanks！

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  TextEditingController folderController = TextEditingController();
  var name = 'xyz';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const htmlData = r"""<tr>
                <td width="28%" align="right" valign="middle" class="labelfont">$name: </td>
                <td width="65%" align="left" valign="middle"><input
                      type="text" name="NAME" class="signuptextfield" value=$name  autocomplete="off"/></td>
                <td width="7%" align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>""";

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test App'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  name = folderController.text;
                });
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.play_arrow,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 60,
              )),
          TextFormField(
            style: mediumTextBoldStyle(textColor: AppColors.mainFontColor),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: 'FolderName',
              hintStyle: hintTextStyle(textColor: AppColors.hintFontColor),
              enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.hintFontColor),
              ),
              focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: AppColors.mainFontColor),
              ),
            ),
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
            controller: folderController,
            onChanged: (value) {},
          ),
          Html(
            data: htmlData,
            style: {
              "table": Style(
                color: Colors.red,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              ),
            },
          ),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `r` (not regular expression) to enable string interpolation.

```dart
void main() {
  String name = 'xyz';

  String htmlData = """<tr>
    <td width="28%" align="right" valign="middle" class="labelfont">$name: </td>
    <td width="65%" align="left" valign="middle"><input
          type="text" name="NAME" class="signuptextfield" value=$name  autocomplete="off"/></td>
    <td width="7%" align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>""";

  print(htmlData); 
  /* <tr>
    <td width="28%" align="right" valign="middle" class="labelfont">xyz: </td>
    <td width="65%" align="left" valign="middle"><input
          type="text" name="NAME" class="signuptextfield" value=xyz  autocomplete="off"/></td>
    <td width="7%" align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  */
}
```